# How to use collection as a predicate to filter arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Assuming I have a huge collection of arrays (100K records) lets say(`sourceArray`). I have a list of another array(`matchIds`) I need to use to filter from this `sourceArray`. How do I achieve this with lodash? or plain JavaScript?

```
var sourceArray = [{
    "id": 123,
  },
  {
    "id": 456
  },
  {
    "id": 789
  },
  {
    "id": 111
  },
  {
    "id": 222
  },
  {
    "id": 333
  }];


var matchIds = [123, 222];
```

The below filter only matches on a single item

```
console.log(
      _.filter(sourceArray, function(arr){
         return arr.id === 123;
      })
    );
```

http://jsbin.com/fegipuwuwa/1/edit?html,js,console

What I would actually expect is `arr.id <..in..> matchIds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your predicate data structure is not optimum and affects the overall performance negatively by increasing the size. It would be best if you first convert `[123, 222]` into a hash or map. Once it's done the rest is just O(n).

```js
var matchIds = [123, 222],
        hash = matchIds.reduce((h,id) => (h[id] = true, h),{}) 
 sourceArray = [{
    "id": 123,
  },
  {
    "id": 456
  },
  {
    "id": 789
  },
  {
    "id": 111
  },
  {
    "id": 222
  },
  {
    "id": 333
  }];
      result = sourceArray.filter(o => hash[o.id]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: matchIds is going to be max. of 20 ids.. only the sourceArray is huge(100K to 150K at times)

Comment: @FakirTrappedInCode So... this will save you from making 150K index of over 20 items what sums up to 3M wasteful operation.

Comment: Thanks. Assume if matchIds = [123, 222, 999, 1111], how do I return only 999,1111. As I see Iam actually only interested in these non-matched ids since I would then call another API to return response for those ids..

Comment: Well... if you would like keep a track of unmatched ids then you can do this in the hash table. In the filter callback function if you do something like `sourceArray.filter(o => hash[o] && (hash[o] = false, true))` then the remaining hash properties with true are untouched which means they don't exist in your `sourceArray`

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply

```
var matchingArray = sourceArray.filter( function(item){
  return matchIds.indexOf(item.id) != -1 
});
```

This will return all the items which are matching from `matchIds`